# Custom inputView not animating correctly during modal presentation

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, presentmodalviewcontroller, inputview

I start by presenting a viewController modally, using the default animation where the view appears from bottom to top. In viewWillAppear, I give first responder to a text field that has a custom keyboard as its inputView. When the view animates for modal presentation, this custom keyboard appears instantly and the rest of the view animates behind it from bottom to top. When I use the default keyboard, it animates correctly with the rest of the view.

How can I get the custom keyboard view to animate while the main view is animating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your `UITextField` the first responder inside `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: That did it! Strange. Can you offer any explanation as to why that worked?